# group by in array using nested array's object field value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping, underscore.js

I have an array like this

```
data = [
  { name : "sa", attributes : [{skin : "green"},{nose:"good"}]},
  { name : "sa", attributes : [{skin : "red"},{nose:"bad"}]},
  { name : "sa", attributes : [{skin : "green"},{nose:"good"}]},
  { name : "sa", attributes : [{nose:"good}]},
]
```

so i want the grouping of array based on skin attribute. I am using  _ underscore library like this

```
const attributeType = "skin";
const groupedCollections = _.groupBy(colls, (col) => {
  const data = col.attributes.find((attribute) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(attribute);
    return keys.indexOf(attributeType) > -1 ? true : false
  });
  return data?.value
});
```

but this is making grouping under `undefined`.

Any help?

Comment: What about using [`keys.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of `keys.indexOf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the value of the wanted property.

```js
const
    colls = [{ name: "sa", attributes: [{ skin: "green" }, { nose: "good" }] }, { name: "sa", attributes: [{ skin: "red" }, { nose: "bad" }] }, { name: "sa", attributes: [{ skin: "green" }, { nose: "good" }] }, { name: "sa", attributes: [{ nose: "good" }] }],
    attributeType = "skin",
    groupedCollections = _.groupBy(colls, ({ attributes }) =>  attributes
        .find(attribute => attributeType in attribute)
        ?.[attributeType]
    );

console.log(groupedCollections);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```